# Linking CSS to HTML file: Path specification

Tags: html, css

No matter how I link my stylesheet, the resulting page remains unstyled.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  test test test
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

body {
  background-color: #f25f29;
}
```

Both files are located in the same folder, which is `test` inside the xampp `htdocs` folder. Another website with stylesheet, which I have taken from a book in another subfolder inside `htdocs` is just fine. (I tried to figure out the mistake in my own page based on the working one, but I couldn't find it)

I already tried the following things:

- different paths

  - `style.css`
  - `./style.css`
  - `/opt/lampp/htdocs/test/style.css`
  - `file://opt/lampp/htdocs/test/style.css`
  - `/test/style.css` (since I guessed that the localhost takes htdocs as root directory)
  - `file://test/style.css`
- matching the `charset` specifier in CSS and HTML files (all uppercase)
- using `/>` to close the link instead of `>`
- inserting a space between linkname and closing bracket
- `sudo chmod 777 *` inside the test folder (changed it back to 644)
- restarting xampp
- omitting the `type="text/css"` specification
- quadruple-checking the name of the stylesheet and its path
- I've had it never enclosed in `<style>` tags
- Also always used the straight quotation signs instead of the "italic" ones

The version that I have given above is the one that works in the other case.

Edit: Clearing the cache the cache fixed it, as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache? I had this problem before where my stylesheet was not updated when i did everything right. I cleared the cache and it worked.

Comment: Have you had a look at your developper tools? Check the network tab to see if the stylesheet is fetched, and at what URL.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/x6x3bcxw/ all work fine, can you give a full css and html?

Comment: @DmitriyLishtvan what are you trying to show in your fiddle? It produces a 404... Nothing better than OP...

Comment: @Salketer i can open this fiddle, and you have 404?

Comment: @DmitriyLishtvan I can see it perfectly fine.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/IwjaDuY.png — I can't reproduce the problem. Whatever it is, it isn't caused by the code in the question. Try opening the developer tools in your browser. Firefox probably has the best tools for debugging CSS errors. Look at the network tab and see if the CSS loads correctly. Look at the console while ensuring that the CSS errors are being reported (there are a bunch of filter buttons on the UI)

Comment: @Granny: Thanks a lot, it was just clearing the cache and now it works. I always thought that cache would be cleared automatically when I restart the browser.

Comment: @tillyboy Ill make an awnser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When CSS is not updating on your website, it could be that the website has an older version of the stylesheet in the cache. Clearing this will make it fetch the updated version.

To find out if this is the problem:

1. Right click on page and inspect (element)
2. Navigate to Sources
3. Navigate to your Stylesheet
4. check if this is the updated version.

If your stylesheet is not up to date, clear cache and check if it worked.

**For example:**

[Clear cache in Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

[Clear cache in Internet Explorer](https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=15141)

[Clear cache in Mozilla Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache)

Comment: You could also edit your post and tell that a hint to the older stylesheet can be found in the css that you can see in your dev-tools. In my case it was empty.